# Get Active Directory Information from PC's in a text file - Powershell

Tags: active-directory, powershell-3.0

I am running to an issue with a Powershell command line I'm attempting to run.  What we are needing is to get the PC Name and LastLogonDate from PC's in a list of text files with Powershell.

Here is the code I'm attempting to run:

```
Get-Content C:\Hosts.txt | ForEach-Object{Get-ADComputer $_ -Properties Name,LastLogonDate | Select-Object Name,LastLogonDate | Export-Csv C:\Output.csv}
```

When I run that code I get an error stating: "Cannot find a object with identity: 'ComputerName'" despite the fact that the PC is truly in AD. What is confusing me is that everything after the ForEach-Object runs great if you run it by itself. When you add the Get-Content and ForEach-Object the errors begin. I can see from the error messages that each individual computer name is being read from the text file, but I wonder if it is passing it in a way the Get-ADComputer doesn't like.

Comment: Can you give an example of your Hosts.txt, according to your error it begins with 'computername'

Comment: Just realized this was still unanswered, my apologies. I have no idea why this wasn't working before, but I tested it at the new company I'm at and things are working just fine.  I did add an append the export command, but other than that it worked exactly how it should.  Must have been a bizarre fluke in that particular environment.  


Get-Content C:\Hosts.txt | ForEach-Object{Get-ADComputer $_ -Properties Name,LastLogonDate | Select-Object Name,LastLogonDate | Export-Csv C:\Output.csv -Append}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things.  First is to see what's in the hosts.txt file.  Second thing is to move the Export-Csv command outside of the ForEach-Object statement.  If you leave it how it is, it will only return the last object it processed in the csv file.  I've posted an example of how it should be.

```
Get-Content C:\Hosts.txt | ForEach-Object {Get-ADComputer $_ -Properties Name,LastLogonDate | Select-Object Name,LastLogonDate} | Export-Csv C:\Output.csv
```

I'm not able to replicate your problem and the only thing different is the contents of the hosts.txt file so it would be helpful to see it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm at a new company now and it works just fine using a regular old text file with 1 computer name per line, just as expected.  Must have been a fluke in the old environment.  Only think I needed to add was a -Append to the Csv export.